# How to put data directly into the printer spooler?

Tags: printer

I want to put data directly into the printer spooler.

Is it possible?

The intention behind this is to convert file or data to printer format, send that data to one computer and from there, a service will print the document in a specific order and configuration.

I have following setup for test:

1. HP 1020.
2. Pentium 4 Machine.

Comment: for the "print across network" feature, take a look at e.g. samba networked printing. also please specify your OS(ses).

Answer (score 0):

You can Print to File. Go to Printer Properties, and click the Ports tab.

If you select FILE: as the port, the driver will ask for a file name at print time. This may suit the way you want to work, but I suspect that you want to automate it further. In that case, do the following:

Create a new Local Port, with the path and file name for the output, e.g. Z:\prints\newjob.prt

The driver will now always use that file name - but you probably require a different name for each job. That can be achieved by running a script, loaded at startup, that does the following:

1. look for Z:\prints\newjob.prt
2. When it appears rename it. You can add an incremental number, or add the time and date to the name, or whatever suits you.
3. Wait a suitable time (seconds, minutes...) and loop to the beginning.

Comment: "Go to Printer Properties" where? I remember this being possible in Windows 98, but without the asker specifying their OS, at least you should when answering clearly OS dependent.

Comment: @nonchip Yes, we need to know the OS. As the PC is a "Pentium 4 machine" I assumed Windows, and Printer Properties is available in all versions of Windows, from 95 to 8.

Comment: ok, didn't know about the other win versions, because I never used a printer with them :D and I guess the backslashed paths are enough information for any experienced non-windows-user to see this is aimed at windows, so I guess it's fine :P I just have a bit of a problem with software being "for PC and mac" when it really means "for windows and OSX", and with a question about low-level driver stuff like this, the asker should really supply more information than just the (irrellevant) CPU :P